# How do Fix these errors with android camera app?

Tags: android, android-camera

I checked the log cat in android studio and these are the errors it displays

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters
android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()'on a null object reference

at .easyCamView.takePicture(easyCamView.java:146)
```

Actual Code:

```
mPictureFileName = fileName; Parameters params =
mCamera.getParameters();
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at .easyCamView.surfaceCreated(easyCamView.java:191)
```

```
Intent openIntent = new Intent();
openIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mContext.startActivity(openIntent); mCamera = Camera.open();
```

at easyCamActivity.captureScreen(easyCamActivity.java:179)

`mCameraView.takePicture(fileName);`

I am able to compile the code but it crashes whenever I run it. if I can get some help that would be great.

Comment: show me your androidManifest.xml file

Comment: I have posted the manifest file below.

Answer (score 0):

```
***<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false"/>

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        
        <activity android:name=".CamActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>***
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                      android:required="true" />

<application>
   ...
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

inside your java File

```
   static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
        
       
    
    //Take a photo with a camera app
         private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        
        
        //Get the thumbnail
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
    
    
    String currentPhotoPath;
    
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );
    
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    
    
    
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ...
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                      "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                      photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }


//Add your Image to Gallery.
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

// NOT REQUIRED if you want to decode a scaled image

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```